# How to write dynamic xpath in cypress

Tags: xpath, cypress

Say i have elements

```
 <div id="Test1">
      <p text="One"> One </p>
 </div>

 <div id="Test2">
      <p text="One">  One </p>
 </div>

 <div id="Test3"> 
      <p text="One"> One </p>
 </div>

 <div id="Test4"> 
      <p text="One"> One </p>
 </div>
```

Now i want to locate the text element dynamically based on div id. Something like

```js
getText(divID){
  cy.get("divID").find("vasErrorMessage").
}
```

How to write code in cypress for this. Here I will send divID dynamically and divID can be Test2 or Test1

Comment: Please show us your code trials. What specific problems, errors have you faced?

Answer (score 3):

When using an Id as CSS selector, it needs to be prefixed with a hash.

```
getElementById(id) {
    const selector = "#" + id;
    return cy.get(selector);
}
```

There is no need for xpath, which is not supported by Cypress out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.contains()` to get the proper element.

```js
// gets third id=Test3 element with 'One' text
cy.contains('#Test3', 'One')
```